# Unmanaged C++ to call C# dll with automatic registration when buildning or without COM?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, dllregistration

I have a function in C++ that needs to call a C# dll.
The C++ function simply sends values to the C# dll functions.
The C# dll uses these values to produce some files and then finishes.

My problem is that when using COM I need to register the DLL everytime when using a different computer. 
So, is there any way to register the dll file and produce a .tlb file on build?

copy $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir) C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe $(TargetPath) /codebase CReportGenerationDLL.dll /tlb:CReportGenerationDLL.tlb

This is what i have tried, but it wont work.. I get exited with code 9009

//Pewdut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your meaning is to register your COM object automatically each time when **building** your application on another compputer, then the answer is (assuming you are using  VS2010 for building) :
Go to Project/Properties/Build events and add to the "Post-build event command line"
the following line:

```
regasm <path to your COM .dll>
```

If your meaning is to register your COM object automatically each time when **running** your application on another compputer, then you can create a batch file which contains:

```
regasm <path to your COM .dll>
<path to your application>app.exe"
```

Or just call regasm.exe from your application using ShellExecute function.

You may want to add /s switch to make the registration silent.

Error 9009 says that your path to regasm is wrong, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908268)

copy $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir) is out of place, why do you need this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: copy $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe $(TargetPath) /codebase CReportGenerationDLL.dll /tlb:CReportGenerationDLL.tlb

This is what i have tried, but it wont work.. I dont think regsvr32 is right in this context, sorry if i discribed my problem poorly.